# if value within range, return column

Tags: r

I have 2 different dataframes

```
str(drivenum)
'data.frame':   95841 obs. of  7 variables:
 $ team: chr  "SF" "ATL" "SF" "ATL" ...
 $ year: int  2000 2000 2000 2000 2000 2000 2000 2000 2000 2000 ...
 $ opp : chr  "ATL" "SF" "ATL" "SF" ...
 $ drvn: int  1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 ...
 $ fpid: int  2 12 19 23 36 40 54 58 66 71 ...
 $ lpid: num  9 17 22 34 39 52 57 64 70 75 ...
 $ pts : num  6 3 0 3 0 3 0 3 0 6 ...

str(drivedata)
'data.frame':   669217 obs. of  7 variables:
 $ team: chr  "SF" "SF" "SF" "SF" ...
 $ year: int  2000 2000 2000 2000 2000 2000 2000 2000 2000 2000 ...
 $ opp : chr  "ATL" "ATL" "ATL" "ATL" ...
 $ pid : int  1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 ...
 $ dwn : int  0 1 2 1 2 1 1 1 2 0 ...
 $ ytg : int  0 10 9 10 6 10 10 6 4 0 ...
 $ yfog: int  0 26 27 37 41 60 70 94 96 0 ...
```

I am trying to return the drivenum$drvn if the drivedata$pid falls between the range of drivenum$fpid and drivenum$lpid, but I am running into issues because of the different sized dataframes. Anyone have any ideas?

Comment: You can check `?foverlaps` from `library(data.table)`

Answer (score 0):

You can use `which` to find the rows in `drivenum` that apply to a given value in `drivedata$pid`:

```
drivenum <- data.frame( fpid = c( 2, 12, 19, 23, 36 ),
                        lpid = c( 9, 17, 22, 34, 39 ),
                        drvn = c( 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 ) )

drivedata <- data.frame( pid = 1:20 )

drvn.list <- sapply( drivedata$pid,
                     function(x){ drivenum$drvn[which((drivenum$fpid <= x) & (x <= drivenum$lpid))]})
```

.

```
> drvn.list
[[1]]
numeric(0)

[[2]]
[1] 1

[[3]]
[1] 1

[[4]]
[1] 1

[[5]]
[1] 1

[[6]]
[1] 1

[[7]]
[1] 1

[[8]]
[1] 1

[[9]]
[1] 1

[[10]]
numeric(0)

[[11]]
numeric(0)

[[12]]
[1] 2

[[13]]
[1] 2

[[14]]
[1] 2

[[15]]
[1] 2

[[16]]
[1] 2

[[17]]
[1] 2

[[18]]
numeric(0)

[[19]]
[1] 3

[[20]]
[1] 3

>
```

Here is an alternative solution that works if

- for each value in `drivedata$pid` there is at most one value in `drivenum$drvn` and
- the columns `drivenum$fpid` and `drivenum$lpid` are ordered increasingly, i.e. `divenum$fpid[i]<drivenum$fpid[j]` if `i<j` and similarly for `drivenum$lpid`.

It is faster, though it contains a loop. So loops are *not always* that bad.

```
drvn.list.2 <- lapply(as.list(as.integer(rep(0,nrow(drivedata)))),head,0)
pos <- rep(NA,max(drivenum$lpid))
pos[drivedata$pid] <- 1:nrow(drivedata)

for ( i in 1:nrow(drivenum) )
{
  if (max(drivedata$pid)<drivenum$fpid[i]) { break() }

  drvn.list.2[pos[drivenum$fpid[i]:drivenum$lpid[i]]] <-
    drivenum$drvn[i]
}
```

Speed comparison using an example with `drivenum` of size 8000 and `drivedata` of size 60000:

```
#---------------------------------------------------------
# Generate example data:

set.seed(1)

n <- 8000
d1 <- sample(1:3,n,replace=TRUE)
d2 <- sample(1:10,n,replace=TRUE)

drivenum <- data.frame( fpid = cumsum(d1+(c(0,d2)[-n])),
                        lpid = cumsum(d1+d2),
                        drvn = sample(1:n) )

drivedata <- data.frame( pid = sample(1:60000) )

#----------------------------------------------------------
# Speed comparison:

system.time(
  for ( k in 1:10 )
  {
    drvn.list.1 <- sapply( drivedata$pid,
                           function(x){ drivenum$drvn[which((drivenum$fpid <= x) & (x <= drivenum$lpid))] } )
  }
)

system.time(
  for ( k in 1:10 )
  { 
    drvn.list.2 <- lapply(as.list(as.integer(rep(0,nrow(drivedata)))),head,0)
    pos <- rep(NA,max(drivenum$lpid))
    pos[drivedata$pid] <- 1:nrow(drivedata)

    for ( i in 1:nrow(drivenum) )
    {
      if (max(drivedata$pid)<drivenum$fpid[i]) { break() }

      drvn.list.2[pos[drivenum$fpid[i]:drivenum$lpid[i]]] <-
        drivenum$drvn[i]
    }
  }
)
```

.

```
> system.time(
+   for ( k in 1:10 )
+   {
+     drvn.list.1 <- .... [TRUNCATED] 
   user  system elapsed 
 432.12    0.46  436.73 

> system.time(
+   for ( k in 1:10 )
+   { 
+     drvn.list.2 <- lapply(as.list(as.integer(rep(0,nrow(drivedata)))),head,0)
+     pos <- rep(NA,max(dr .... [TRUNCATED] 
   user  system elapsed 
  51.07    0.03   51.41 
>
```

The results coincide:

```
> identical(drvn.list.1,drvn.list.2)
[1] TRUE
>
```

Comment: Awesome, thanks a ton, this does work. Any ideas on how to speed this up? It takes a little over 22 minutes to run on the full dataset.

Comment: I enhanced my answer by a second, faster solution.